# Handling exceptions and executing code if one was found

Tags: c#, exception-handling, exception

I have this code:

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input number {0}", i + 1);
    int number = ReadNumber(start, end);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is ArgumentException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The input number wasn't in the alowed range. Please try again.");
    }
    else if (ex is FormatException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The input isn't an integer number. Please try again.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An unknown error occured. Please try again.");
    }

    i--;
}
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this - catch all exceptions and handle them and then, if any exception was caught, I want to reduce `i` by 1.

Comment: you can use different catch blocks for different type of exceptions

Comment: I don't think you understood, I want to be able to catch all exceptions and handle them, BUT then have a code that is executed after all catch-es and only if one of them was entered.

Comment: So you want i-- to happen only if an exception is caught, or you want it to happen regardless?

Comment: Only if an exception was caught :) And it works the way I did it, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it. If there is a special operator to do it or something like that.

Comment: This looks fine to me.

Comment: To me this is bad code.  I read an article recently (can't remember where) that said that `catch ( Exception )` is bad.  If you want the same code to run in each case, put it in a method & call that method in each `catch` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I'm assuming that all of this code is in a `for` loop, and that `for` loop is incrementing `i` as it's loop statement.

What you can do here is not unconditionally increment `i` in each iteration of the loop, and instead only increment `i` if you're able to read in the number successfully:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; )
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input number {0}", i + 1);
        int number = ReadNumber(start, end);
        i++;
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The input number wasn't in the alowed range. Please try again.");
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The input isn't an integer number. Please try again.");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An unknown error occured. Please try again.");
    }
}
```

However, for this case I'd say that there's an option that's better still.

What you should really do is, rather than having a method try to get another value from the user and possibly failing and possibly succeeding and needing to be called again, create a method that *keeps asking the user for a value until it gets a valid one*.  This logic is *far* easier to implement at that scope than it is to try to continually add more iterations to the loop.

Once you create a method that will *always* get a valid value, trying as hard as it needs to:

```
public static int ReadNumber(int start, int end, int iteration)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input number {0}", iteration + 1);
        int n;
        if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n))
            Console.WriteLine("The input isn't an integer number. Please try again.");
        else if (n < start || n > end)
            Console.WriteLine("The input number wasn't in the alowed range. Please try again.");
        else
            return n;
    }
}
```

(Also note the use of conditional checks to determine if the user input is valid, rather than using exceptions for non-exceptional control flow.)

Now our loop is dead easy:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int number = ReadNumber(start, end, i);
}
```

Comment: Your answer makes a lot of sense and I like it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could set a `bool` indicating if an exception was caught. I see no superiority in this way, but it exists.
You might also consider catching these in seperate `catch` statements:

```
var wasCaught = false;
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input number {0}", i + 1);
    int number = ReadNumber(start, end);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    wasCaught = true;
    if (ex is ArgumentException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The input number wasn't in the alowed range. Please try again.");
    }
    else if (ex is FormatException)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("The input isn't an integer number. Please try again.");
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("An unknown error occured. Please try again.");
    }
}
if (wasCaught)
{
    i--;
}
```